# Can I scan DynamoDB table without 'Limit' in python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb

Also, if the result exceed max memory limit how can I continue the scan?

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Just use a loop to keep scanning using the LastEvaluatedKey until you reach the end of the table. Beware that scans are expensive in Dynamo in terms of consuming RCUs. Make sure you have enough reserved capacity as well or your requests will be throttled.

Answer (score 1):

From [DynamoDB — Boto 3 documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.scan):

> **scan()**
>
> **Limit** (integer) -- The maximum number of items to evaluate (not necessarily the number of matching items). If DynamoDB processes the number of items up to the limit while processing the results, it stops the operation and returns the matching values up to that point, and a key in `LastEvaluatedKey` to apply in a subsequent operation, so that you can pick up where you left off. Also, **if the processed data set size exceeds 1 MB before DynamoDB reaches this limit, it stops the operation** and returns the matching values up to the limit, and a key in `LastEvaluatedKey` to apply in a subsequent operation to continue the operation.

Comment: would you be able to provide an example of how to use LastEvaluatedKey?